# Finding Current, Logged in userId

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, api-design

I want to access userId of a user who is currently logged in in ASP.NET Core 6. I tried many different approaches, but all of them seem to have one problem: user is always null.

I tried this

```
string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

and I also tried this:

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User); 

var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

And many other things :(.

Part of my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public UsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` method to get the id, you need to make sure the id is in the claims.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginUserDto.UserName);
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginUserDto.UserName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
};
```

[image]

Or

You can use `var result = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);` to get the current user first, Then get the id.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rain, Can this answer solve your issue?

Comment: Still null. :( I think frontend does not attach correct header or something and that's why it's null. when ran from swagger it works yes